# How do I filter text so I can convert part of it to a currency?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some numbers that I need to convert to a currency. I am using this script to do the conversion (https://github.com/CodersPress/jQuery-Currency) which works on one of my numbers but not the other. I can't work out how to target the number in the li (I can't modify the html output in this case). I tried to filter the text to re-position the ':' from the number in the li but still can't get the currency conversion to work on the number in the li.

I have a fiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/dcrr5qxf/5/

Here is my html:

```
<ul class="cfeature">                              
    <li class="purchase_price"><label>Purchase Price</label>: 333333</li>
</ul>
<p class="purchase_price">
    <label>Purchase Price:&nbsp;</label>
    <strong><span>333333.00</span></strong>
</p>
```

Here is my js:

```
$('.purchase_price').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace(":", ""));
});
$('.purchase_price').each(function() {
    $(this).html($(this).html().replace("Purchase Price", "Purchase Price:"));
});

$(".purchase_price span").currency(); // this one works as the number is in a <span>
$(".purchase_price").currency(); // this one doesn't work
});

});
```

Comment: It works if that is the only number you have in that class: https://jsfiddle.net/dcrr5qxf/6/

Comment: Thanks but the number is dynamic and isn't converting the number in the <li>.

Comment: Please find my answer below with working code and jsFiddle demo. Please upvote and mark it as accepted if you find it good enough.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can solve this problem looping over the `<li>`'s and performing following 3 steps on each of it:

1. wrap the number in a `<div>` and give it a class, say `forCurrency`
2. apply `.currency()` to this `<div>` and get the corresponding text
3. replace the wrapped `<div>` with the text that we just got

---

jQuery:

```
    $("ul.cfeature > li").each(function(){

        // wrap the number in a div
        $(this).html(function(_, html) {
            return html.replace(/(\d+)\s*$/, "<div id='forCurrency'>$1</div>");
        });

        // apply .currency() and get the corresponding text
        var currencyText = $("div#forCurrency").currency().text();
        console.log(currencyText);

        // replace the wrapped div with the text that we just got
        $("div#forCurrency").replaceWith(currencyText);

    });
```

---

[Updated jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dcrr5qxf/16/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Rahul. I have multiple instances of the li on my page (property listings), each with the same html structure and noticed that when I run your code it groups all of the numbers into one string. Is there any way to change this so that it can handle multiple instances?

Comment: @Greg In that case, you need to loop over each `li` and apply the same logic, but using an ID, not a class like we did earlier. See this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/dcrr5qxf/16/ Answer updated.

Comment: Thanks Rahul! I have accepted your answer but can't upvote it as I need to improve my reputation first :) I will be sure to come back and do this once I have!